# How do I point with my straight line the point that moves in the figure "infinite" / "8"?

Tags: unity, c#

I need a help for my project.

Given a straight line "a" - "b"
I have "a" point anchored and "b" can move.
I need to make sure that the "b" point of the straight line always points to the "c" point, taking into consideration that "a" is anchored.

I can not use the LookAt () because I need to be able to use the mouse too.
[image]

Comment: "I can not use the LookAt () because I need to be able to use the mouse too. " can you explain what you mean by that? Will point `c` be controlled by the mouse in some occasions?

Comment: @TomTsagk Practically the point "a" is the character holding the weapon, the point "b" is the barrel of my rifle. I need to make sure that the moment when my character is aiming the rifle moves like in games and does not have a fixed point.

Comment: Are these just Vector3 points/offsets, or GameObjects like meshes, sprites, etc? It's not clear from the limited context we can see why using "LookAt" on the rifle would interfere with use of the mouse for the camera, for instance. The more clearly you can demonstrate your situation & setup, the more accurately we'll be able to help.

Comment: Oh, oh, I get it.  @DMGregory he wants to add muzzle wobble top a FPS game: the camera should wiggle slightly as the user aims, but the view direction should still be driven by mouse-look.

Comment: @Draco18s good insight! That still shouldn't interfere with using LookAt on the rifle though, while the camera remains mouse controlled, should it? EIRU, including context for what you're trying to do like Draco18s describes can be a big help to get users on the same page quickly and get better answers, so I recommend editing that into your question if it's accurate.

Comment: Firing angle would also be adjusted by the same amount. I have an idea of how to approach it, but need to sit down and fiddle with it.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted to say.
Thanks @Draco18s for your intuition.

DMGregory , do you have any suggestions on how best to describe my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just take the AC vector, which should contain AB, since AB points at C, then normalize it and multiply by the length of AB. To get B, simply add the resulting vector to A.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches to try and see which works (or works better).

As both of my computers have committed suicide, I can't test these myself.

## Option 1: using the hierarchy

Assumptions: Your character is directly controlled via `MouseLook`, your camera is a child of the character.

Approach: Add an additional child object between your character and your camera. Add a script to this. Use `LookAt()` as described in the question to rotate this object, which will introduce the jitter to the camera (don't bother jiggling the weapon model, you're going to use the camera to determine shot angle anyway).

## Option 2: direct jiggle

Assumptions: None

Approach: After mouselook runs, do the following:

```
Vector2 offset = InfinityLoop(Time.time);

Vector3 lookPoint = cam.transform.forward * 10 + offset;
cam.transform.LookAt(lookPoint);

private Vector2 InfinityLoop(float time) {
    //calculate your jiggle loop
}
```

For either approach:

When the jiggle is not required, either disable the jiggle script or otherwise don't calculate/apply the jiggle.